# Get function ("f(x)") from polynomial regression (graph)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, regression, integration

I did polynomial regression on some data.
The graph was plotted. But how do I get the function "f(x)" of the plotted graph? I like to integrate the function!

```
 z = np.polyfit(x, y1, 6)  
 p = np.poly1d(z) 

 xp = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
 line = plt.plot(x, y1, '.', xp, p(xp), '-', label=' G_MEAN_1 ')
 plt.ylim(0, 1)
 plt.legend()
 plt.show()
```

So how can I get the function out of here - for integration?

Comment: Also check [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyint.html) out

Answer (score 0):

As

```
    p = np.poly1d(z)
```

returns a function, you can use "p" for integration. So to get the integral form 0.3 to 0.6, you can go via:

```
integrate.quad(p, 0.3, 0.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a good sense your variable `p` already *is* that function. Have a look at the usage examples in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html).

If you want a string representation to the effect of *"x^2 + 4x - 5"*, it looks like you could just cast it to string. The handling of the exponents in the `print()` examples looks a little weird to me though.